# How to remove grid column header highlight (bold + underline) when applying menu filter in Ext Js?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have been using Ext Js' grid panel with menus applied to the column headers (default).

Whenever I apply a filter to the column through the menu, the column header gets highlighted with it's title getting bold and underlined.

I have tried to find a way to remove it, but could not find any event or method to solve this problem. I want my application to remove all highlights before applying a new one, so that it becomes impossible to have 2 columns with highlights on their title simultaneously.

Is there any way to implement this? Or simply disable the highlights, so that no column header titles get highlighted when filtered...

Obs: I am applying a store.clearFilter() whenever the column filter is changed, and the header is still not getting back to normal.

Obs2: Could not post images to illustrate due to stack's reputation restrictions (second time posting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple override the `filterCls` to remove the highlight:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.filters.Filters, {filterCls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Still, is there any way to track if the filter is applied to the column header, so I can add/remove it programmatically? 

I looked into filter.filter and column.column documentation and could not find any.